# Data not selecting when testing SQL

Tags: sql, select

I am currently testing SQL code for my website and when doing so, the values which I am selected are displaying in the table in stead of the actual data passing over, as such:

Output of sql query
[image: Output of SQL query]

Here is the SQL code which I am using to generate said output:

```
SELECT "a.ID", "a.Name" FROM w_Continent Order by "a.Name";
```

Table I am selecting from:
[image: This is the table I am selecting from]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Lose the double quotes around a.id and a.name

Comment: Please remove the surrounding quotes and it will work fine.

Comment: When loosing the double quotes, I receive the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'a.ID' in 'field list'

Comment: Your sample code uses a.ID meaning you aliased the table in your FROM, but you actually dont have the a alias anywhere. I would recommend going and doing some basic MySQL tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT "a.ID", "a.Name" FROM w_Continent Order by "a.Name";
```

Issues with Your select:

- There is no table alias **a** defined
- The double quotes makes the text "a.Id" to a literal

Your query should be:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name FROM w_Continent a Order by a.Name;
```

Or without table alias:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM w_Continent Order by Name;
```

Or if there are only two columns;

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing that is because the double quotes makes it into a literal string instead of a column name.

```
SELECT a.name, "a.name"
FROM your_table a
```

Specifically for your code:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM w_Continent Order by Name;
```

or

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name FROM w_Continent a Order by a.Name;
```

Comment: When loosing the double quotes, I receive the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'a.ID' in 'field list'

Comment: Are you using a as the alias for the table? What happens when you do ID instead of a.ID?

Comment: Problem solved with following code, thank you: SELECT ID as contID, Name as contName from w_Continent order by contName

Comment: @JamesSwann I added code to my answer. Both of those should work fine for you.

Comment: Hi, I ended up using: SELECT ID as contID, Name as contName from w_Continent order by contName and it worked, thank you for your time!